# React Router match property null when using custom Route component

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I am using the `ConnectedRouter` component and a custom Route like so:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ layout: Layout, component: Component, rest }) => (

  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={matchProps => (
      <AuthConsumer>
        {({ authenticated }) =>
          authenticated ? (
            <Layout pathname={matchProps.location.pathname}>
              <Component {...matchProps} />
            </Layout>
          ) : (
            <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: matchProps.location } }} />
          )
        }
      </AuthConsumer>
    )}
  />
)
```

which I use like this:

```
<Switch>
    <PrivateRoute
      exact
      path={`${match.url}someroute/:id`}
      layout={Layout}
      component={SomePage}
    />
</Switch>
```

And a component like so:

```
import React from 'react'

const SomePage = ({ match }) => {
  console.log('MATCH ', match.params)
  return <div>TESTING</div>
}

export default SomePage
```

In this case, `match` is empty, and it thinks its on the '/' route (even though `location` prop says its on `/someroute/123`.

On the other hand, this works:

```
<Route
      exact
      path={`${match.url}someroute/:id`}
      component={SomePage}
    />
```

and match gets updated properly.

I'm stumped as to why this is happening.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I figure it out.  `rest` should have been `...rest`, the `<Route>` component wasn't getting the props passed down correctly!